# Create a new column in a SQL query with IF/ELSE logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm working on a query that pulls a list of people who visited a certain location. Part of the location's policy is that if a person hasn't visited within 3 years, they're no longer an active member and would have to re-establish their membership. Normally I just paste my query results into Excel and add a column with a formula that looks at the last visit date and flags whether the person is active or not, but I thought I might try to add that calculation directly to my query and have SQL Server do the work for me. Problem is, I'm not sure about the syntax.

I'd like my end result to look something like this (I typically have my Excel formula just look 3 years back from the date I'm creating the report, so for the purposes of this example, we're looking 3 years back from 12/17/2019):

```
PersonID    LastVisit     Active
-------------------------------------
1001        2019-12-01    YES
1002        2014-07-24   
1003        2016-12-31    YES
1004        2018-10-12    YES
1005        2016-02-04
1006        2017-09-20    YES
```

If I'm understanding right from some of the research I've tried to do so far, this would require a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT
   PersonID,
   LastVisit,
   CASE [--not sure what, if anything, goes here--]
      WHEN LastVisit > DATEADD(yy,-3,GETDATE()) THEN 'YES'
      END AS Active

FROM PersonInfo
ORDER BY PersonID
```

As it stands now, I've got a couple of syntax errors: `incorrect syntax near '>'` and `incorrect syntax near 'THEN'`. Am I at least on the right track? What do I need to do to get this logic to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax should work:

```
(CASE WHEN LastVisit > DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE()) THEN 'YES'
 END) AS Active
```

By the way, this is called a `case` *expression* in SQL.

Comment: That did the trick! I had a hunch it might have to do with the placement of parentheses. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the parenthesis was the issue.  I think it was the square brackets you have in there. Which I'm guessing you may have copied out of some documentation?

Comment: hm, it might have been, though I didn't notice the errors go away when I got rid of those brackets. I didn't have the full CASE expression () in parenthesis though, which probably wasn't helping

Comment: You shouldn't need the full case expression in parenthesis.  Adding the parenthesis here doesn't actually get at the root of the problem.  Go ahead and try removing the paren before the CASE and the one after END.  It should still run just fine.

Comment: @EJF . . . The parentheses are optional.  I always include them with complex expressions so it is clear where the expression begins and ends.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff so if the parenthesis are optional would you agree that the main reason your answer works is that you dropped the square brackets or is there something else going on

Answer (score 2):

The only actual issue I see with your code is your square brackets.  You start the comment after your first square bracket in the case statement.  If you remove the unnecessary stuff or start the comment earlier it should work.

Removing the comment entirely:

```
SELECT
   PersonID,
   LastVisit,
   CASE 
      WHEN LastVisit > DATEADD(yy,-3,GETDATE()) THEN 'YES'
      END AS Active

FROM PersonInfo
ORDER BY PersonID
```

Alternatively just start your comment earlier

```
SELECT
   PersonID,
   LastVisit,
   CASE --[not sure what, if anything, goes here--]
      WHEN LastVisit > DATEADD(yy,-3,GETDATE()) THEN 'YES'
      END AS Active

FROM PersonInfo
ORDER BY PersonID
```